# Enable and focus Textfield at once in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm trying to implement a `TextField` in Jetpack Compose with the following functionality: at first it is disabled, but when a user presses the `Button`, it gets enabled and at the same moment receives focus. This was my approach:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("text") }
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        enabled = enabled,
        modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp)
    )
    Button(onClick = {
        enabled = true
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }) {
        Text("Enable and request focus")
    }
```

But when the button is pressed, the `TextField` only gets enabled, not focused. To focus it, user has to click it once again. What am I doing wrong and what is the possible workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You have to listen the change of the `enabled` parameter to give the focus to the `TextField`.

You can change your code to:

```
    Button(onClick = {
        enabled = true

    }) {
        Text("Enable and request focus")
    }

    LaunchedEffect(enabled) {
        if (enabled){
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a solution I was looking for.

Comment: There's still a problem that keyboard remains hidden even though the TextField has received focus.

Comment: @IvanAbramov I've tried the code with `1.0.5` and `1.1.0-rc01` and the keyboard appears. I am not able to reproduce your issue. Try to add: `val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current` and call `keyboardController.show()` after `requestFocus()`.

Comment: Thank you, worked when I updated to `1.1.0-rc1`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the delay after enabling textfield like this:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("text") }
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        enabled = enabled,
        modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp)
    )
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            enabled = true
            delay(100)
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }) {
        Text("Enable and request focus")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I only wonder how I know that this 100ms would always be enough?

Comment: If you are not sure if the 100ms delay is enough, i believe the best way is using DisposableEffect as Gabriele answered.

Comment: Why we have to give delay ?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue and I solved it by using `interactionSource`. The code looked something like this:

```kotlin
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("text") }
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() } // add this

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        enabled = enabled,
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusable(interactionSource = interactionSource) // and this
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp)
    )
    ...
```

IIRC it was important to have `.focusable()` and `.focusRequester()` in the right order, but cannot remember which exactly, so try to swap them if it won't work immediately.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these worked :(